# Get Listview sub items in UI Path

Tags: winforms, listview, uipath, uipath-studio

How to get the list view sub items using UI Path RPA.

I tried using data scraping, recording but it output only first sub item data.

I have followed this link regarding same problem but I couldn't understand the xaml file provided in answer.

https://forum.uipath.com/t/data-scraping-listview/118929/10

Comment: Show us an image of your application.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the "Find children" activity on the parent element, so you could retrieve all the list elements.

[image: Find children activity]

You should search for "FIND_DESCENDANTS".

Regards, Gio

Answer (score 0):

If your target client is Windows Forms Ap,you can refer the following:

You must use ui explorer to watch the element attribute

1. uiexplorer's "UI Frameworks" (from menu options/UI Frameworks) change to "UI Automation".
2. indicate element to select which subitem you want.

Then you can see down right selector editor display like
"`<uia automationid='ListViewSubItem-2' tableCol='2' tableRow='10' />`". Watch the left side "visual tree", it show the subitem list. so now what you have to do is to get the item list(it show first subitem) and for each item to get subitem list,finally through get attribute activity to get the subitem value.

the pseudo flow like following:
find_children activity=>for_each activity { find_children activity=> for_each activity { get_attribute activity} }

the first find_children's selector like "`<uia automationid='1000' cls='SysListView32' />`" and filter is like "`<uia automationid='ListViewItem-*'/>`".
the second find_children's selector is for_each item and filter is like "`<uia automationid='ListViewSubItem-1'/>`". the "1" is subitem index.